How to open a new window with dynamic data in a macOS App using SwiftData
I have have edited this question to try to make it more clear and added an Xcode project
To simulate the problem I am trying to solve which is just press a button and open a new window in macOS with a model from SwiftData.
Here is the SwiftDataWindowApp file where I am trying to pass an ItemModel to WindowGroup. I am hoping just to pass the whole model becuase in other SwiftData applications I have never needed an Id.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct SwiftDataWindowApp: App {
   
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .modelContainer(for: [ItemModel.self])
        }
        
// I can't figure out how to pass an ItemModel to WindowGroup this does not work
       
WindowGroup(for: [ItemModel.self]) { $item in
  ItemView(item:$item)
      .modelContainer(for:[ItemModel.self])
}
        
// Example for WindowGroup documentation
        // A window group that displays messages.
         //WindowGroup(for: Message.ID.self) { $messageID in
             //MessageDetail(messageID: messageID)
        // }
        
    }
}

In ItemsButtonView file is where I am calling openWindow
import SwiftUI

struct ItemsButtonView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    let item: ItemModel
  
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("\(item.name )")
                Text("\(item.desc )")
                Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Open Item In New Window")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // Open Item in new window
                           // openWindow(value: item)
                           print("Open Item Button Presed")
                        }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}



My model
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class ItemModel {
    var timestamp: Date
    var name: String
    var desc: String
    
    
    init(timestamp: Date, name: String = "", desc: String = "") {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
    }
}


ItemView file that I want opened in new window.
import SwiftUI

struct ItemView: View {
    let item: ItemModel
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text("Name: \(item.name)")
            Text("Description: \(item.desc)")
            Text("Date: \(item.timestamp)")
        }
        .frame(width:600, height:300)
    }
}




Do it as in the first code snippet but don’t forget to use .modelContainer again

@JoakimDanielson Thanks for suggestion not sure how to use the model id in this case or syntax. Lot's of complaining for Xcode. I updated the question.

You said it yourself that a model class conforms to Identifiable so that of course means that TradeModel already has an id property. It’s a computed property that returns the property persistentModelID

So with this rewritten question what isn’t working, what is actually the issue now?

Same issue just tried to clarify.

First of all I think it's better to have a property for the ModelContainer in this situation instead of creating a new one for each WindowGroup
The below example is from the Xcode template for a SwiftData project.
var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
    let schema = Schema([ItemModel.self])
    let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

    do {
        return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
    }
}()

Then you have a strange type for the WindowGroup, an array of the model type. Since you will pass only one object to openWindow and then to the view it can't be an array and also the type used must conform to Codable so the model type is not a good idea, better to use the ID type for the model
WindowGroup(for: ItemModel.ID.self)

Then there are different ways to handle the ID value we get, in the solution below I directly unwrap it and load the model object before passing it to the view
let context = ModelContext(sharedModelContainer)
if let id, let model = context.model(for: id) as? ItemModel {
    ItemView(item: model)
}

The complete code for the Scene
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        RootView()
    }
    .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)

    WindowGroup(for: ItemModel.ID.self) { $id in
        let context = ModelContext(sharedModelContainer)
        if let id, let model = context.model(for: id) as? ItemModel {
            ItemView(item: model)
        }
    }
}

I am not using the .modelContainer modifier for the second WindowGroup since you are not modifying or doing anything inside the ItemView that requires a ModelContext but if this changes then don't forget to add the modifier.

Thanks @Joakim It means a lot to me. I still in that piecing it together stage.
